# menu buttons show/hide divs with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, menu, click, show-hide

I'm trying to set my page to have multiple "pages" each of which will display when the appropriate menu button is clicked. I want to have the whole thing in one html document, therefore I want to use divs with a show/hide script activated by the nav menu. I've searched and searched and the methods I've found don't seem to be working for me. My divs all stay hidden and clicking the menu doesn't change the active menu item. It's all in this jfiddle:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/XeqNE/

I would appreciate any pointers. Thanks!

Comment: Where's your `activate` function?. And this `$('.menu active').attr('id').slice(0, 4)` should be `$('.menu.active').attr('id').slice(0, 4)`

Comment: There it is : Timestamp: 9/27/2013 10:39:16 AM
Error: ReferenceError: buttonClick is not defined
Source File: http://fiddle.jshell.net/XeqNE/show/
Line: 1

Comment: @j08691 The activate function is the first of the three jquery functions in the script section. 

Milche The buttonClick function is the second jquery function in the script and is called by the onclick attribute of the nav buttons. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an updated fiddle.  You had too many things wrapped in ".ready", and also had a syntax error on the "remove class" statement: http://fiddle.jshell.net/XeqNE/1/

EDIT:

updated Fiddle to remove some more of the errors.  I can't see the actual window in the example to see if it's working to change the div.  The header is huge.  Should be working though: http://fiddle.jshell.net/XeqNE/4/

EDIT 2:

Updated fiddle and wrapped everything in document.ready.  Not receiving any more JS issues but still can't see the first line of text to see if it's working.  I'd imagine it is. http://fiddle.jshell.net/XeqNE/7/

Comment: Is this an actual answer, because it doesn't seem to fix the problem. Still plenty of errors in the code. Might want to make this a comment.

Comment: @Thought Space Designs the menu items are now properly activating and changing their state, however, all the divs are still hidden. I realize I made the header big - sorry! - but you should still be able to see the first line of text to see if it's loading, which it's currently not. Thank you!

Comment: My screen is too low res to see the first line of text.  I'll go back an look again one sec.

Comment: Thank you. It still wasn't working but I realized I was using 'slice()' wrong. I changed 'slice(0,4)' to 'slice(4)' and it works! (I wanted to remove the "load" portion of the button id - first four chars - to change it to the associated div id.) I really appreciate your attention to my issue!